# Error: could not find function "cc" and package ‘epiDisplay’ was built under R version 3.3.3

Tags: r

I have been trying to attach a dataframe and to run 'cc ', this message keep repeating. Assist on how to overcome this.

Am using updated version of Windows 10

```
View(dd)
attach(dd)
cc(case,exp1)
```

> ```
> Error: could not find function "cc"
> ```

```
library(epiDisplay)
Loading required package: foreign
Loading required package: survival
Loading required package: MASS
Loading required package: nnet
Warning messages:
1: package ‘epiDisplay’ was built under R version 3.3.3 
2: package ‘survival’ was built under R version 3.3.3 
3: package ‘MASS’ was built under R version 3.3.3 
4: package ‘nnet’ was built under R version 3.3.3
```